# Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean, function prepare() returns false when using placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I try to prepare statement to sql (mysqli) in php, but there is an error code as written above. This is the code I wrote:

```
 if (!$this->isUserExist($username, $token)) {return false;}
    $tables = array();        
    $tables[0] = "faculty";     
    $tables[1] = "department";  
    $tables[2] = "teacher";     
    $tables[3] = "announcement";
    $ttable = $tables[$table];
    var_dump($ttable); // faculty
    var_dump($id);     // 6
    echo "DELETE FROM ".$ttable." WHERE ".$ttable.".id = ".$id.""; //returns DELETE FROM faculty WHERE faculty.id = 6
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM ? WHERE ?.id = ?"); //Fatal error occurs here
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$ttable,$ttable,$id);
    //$stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->num_rows> 0) {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
```

However if i insert exact statement without any placeholders that is shown in echo my i get no errors, and MySQL database successfully deletes row.

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM faculty WHERE faculty.id = 6"); //no errors occur, executing this statement does affect row in MySQL database
```

Comment: You cannot bind table names and column names. __Over__.

Comment: What is right way to assign both table names and column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system doesn't allow to 'prepare' table names, You should do it this way

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$ttable." WHERE ".$ttable.".id = ?"); //Fatal error occurs here
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
```

Comment: After modifiation of my code according to your answer, everything worked.
Thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: @user3460802 If you liked my answer and did help you, could you vote it?

Comment: I voted up your answer, but since i have less than 15 reputation it isn't shown publicly

Comment: When for example  `$ttable = " faculty --"`, you can say goodbye to all of your recrds.

Answer (score 0):

please read this https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304

Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.

Do something like this:

```
$query =  "DELETE FROM ".$ttable." WHERE ".$ttable.".id = ?";
$stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I applied changes that you suggested and function works properly.

Comment: @user3460802 welcome